# WSS3.0 to SPF2010 migration path

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, migration

there is this plan to retire all old servers and we have been tasked with migrating WSS3.0  to SharePoint Foundation 2010.

WSS 3.0 runs on Windows Server 2003 R2 x86, there is no SQL, everything runs on Windows Internal Database  (with content database being nearly 100GB)

we plan to utilise SharePoint Foundation 2010 which will also have full SQL 2008 R2, all of course running on 64 bit architecture.

What approach would you suggest for this scenario? 
All help much appreciated.

Comment: could you provide details on the nature of the content? (documents, records, discussion threads, metadata, etc.)

Comment: mostly document libraries containing combination of popular file formats (Office files, PDF, DWG, etc.), got there also couple (literally) of custom lists. all run's on out of the box functinality, there is no custom webparts or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

While 100GB is not the largest SP DB around, it clearly indicates that your organization is a regular user of the SharePoint.  To that end, I would recommend a few things:

Start with splitting out SQL to a dedicated server.  The reasons are numerous but include

1. Scalability - the SQL Box can be scaled both in RAM and Disk easily
   as needed.
2. Performance. Both SQL and SharePoint devour CPU cycles and RAM.  By
   sharing the same resources, both are slowed.
3. about a hundred other reasons from Disaster Recovery to backups...

Create 1-3 Virtual Machines for SharePoint, consisting ideally of 2 load balanced Web Front Ends and 1 app server.  Virtuals are relatively cheap but do not shortchange them on CPU or RAM.

This approach will allow your SharePoint farm to grow as the usage of it does - not only for your current site but for any future sites as well (i.e. Intranet Publishing, Training sites, etc..)  There's a lot in 2010 that you might want to consider leveraging.

One last point, when installing your SP2010 environment, be sure to [use a SQL Alias](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/02/02/configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-sharepoint-sql-server-2008/) instead of referring directly to the SQL DB Machine\Instance name.  This allows for greater flexibility down the road should you need to move the databases to another server.